# Center text on image in android?

Tags: android, image, text, center

In my android app I need to display a text on an image. The text is entered by user in an alertDialog. This text I need to center it on the bottom of the image. I draw the text on image with this :

```
private Canvas drawTextImage(Bitmap b) {
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));

        paint.setStrokeWidth(30);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setTextSize(40);
        c.drawText(text, 350, 900, paint);

        c.translate(300, 50);
        return c;
    }
```

My alertDiallg is this :

```
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Enter a text ");
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
    FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(25);
    input.setFilters(FilterArray);

    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            text = input.getText().toString().trim();
            Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmapResult);
            drawTextImage(bitmapResult);
            saveimage();
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    saveimage();
                }
            });

    alert.show();
```

Tehe text has to be center according to it's length. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
Paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
```

on the paint thats used to draw your text.

> **public void setTextAlign (Paint.Align align)**
>
> Set the paint's text alignment. This controls how the text is
>   positioned relative to its origin. LEFT align means that all of the
>   text will be drawn to the right of its origin (i.e. the origin
>   specifieds the LEFT edge of the text) and so on.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setTextAlign%28android.graphics.Paint.Align%29)

---

**Edit:** In draw text you have to specify half the with of your image as the x-coordinate (center), the y-coordinate should stay the same (somewhere along the bottom, depending how high you want it).